# Reordering columns/rows of a pivot_table?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

pandas's pivot_table seems to return columns only in alphabetical order, such that

`pivot_table(tips, 'tip_pct', rows=['sex', 'day'], cols='smoker', aggfunc=len)`

gives:

```
  smoker     No  Yes
sex    day          
Female Fri   2   7  
       Sat   13  15
       Sun   14  4  
       Thur  25  7  
Male   Fri   2   8  
       Sat   32  27
       Sun   43  15
       Thur  20  10
```

If I wanted to put `Thur` above `Fri`, and `Yes` to the left of `No`, how would I go about it?

Comment: It seems like the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234070/reorder-columns-in-pandas-pivot-table is better than the two hacks below

Answer (score 5):

Using [Categories](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html), introduced in pandas 0.15, the 'day' and 'smoker' columns can be converted to categories with predefined order. The pivot_table() would keep them sorted.

```
>>> pt = pd.pivot_table(df, 'tip_pct', index=['sex', 'day'], columns='smoker', aggfunc=pd.np.sum)

smoker      No  Yes
sex    day         
Female Fri   0    4
       Sat   0    5
       Sun   0    5
       Thu   9    3
Male   Fri   0    4
       Sat   1    5
       Sun   1    5
       Thu   9    3

>>> df["day"] = df["day"].astype('category', categories=["Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"])
>>> df["smoker"] = df["smoker"].astype('category', categories = ["Yes", "No"])
>>> pt = pd.pivot_table(df, 'tip_pct', index=['sex', 'day'], columns='smoker', aggfunc=pd.np.sum)

smoker      Yes  No
sex    day         
Female Thu    3   9
       Fri    4   0
       Sat    5   0
       Sun    5   0
Male   Thu    3   9
       Fri    4   0
       Sat    5   1
       Sun    5   1
```

Comment: this syntax is now deprecated. use: `df["day"] = df["day"].astype(pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(categories=["Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]))` instead

Answer (score 2):

Assign dummy values to these variables and then sort the frame on the axes with those values. It's definitely a hack.

```
In [47]: list_of_days = ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']

In [48]: ri = df.reset_index()

In [49]: day = np.unique(ri.day)

In [50]: day_index = [list_of_days.index(d) for d in day]

In [51]: ri['day_index'] = day_index

In [52]: ri
Out[52]:
   day_index     sex   day  no  yes
0          4  female   Fri   1   47
1          5  female   Sat  42   16
2          6  female   Sun  15   48
3          3  female  Thur  15   49
4          4    male   Fri  48   42
5          5    male   Sat  41   14
6          6    male   Sun   6   36
7          3    male  Thur   9   20

In [53]: ri.sort(['sex', 'day_index', 'day']).set_index(['sex', 'day']).drop('day_index', axis=1)
Out[53]:
             no  yes
sex    day
female Thur  15   49
       Fri    1   47
       Sat   42   16
       Sun   15   48
male   Thur   9   20
       Fri   48   42
       Sat   41   14
       Sun    6   36
```

I've only showed the solution for the index but for the columns you can do something similar.

Comment: FYI there's [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/739) for this, albeit rather old.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a different hack than Mr. Cloud's: naming my days

```
[
'      Mon',
'     Tue',
'    Wed',
'   Thu',
'  Fri',
' Sat',
'Sun']
```

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote this answer, but I won't because I'm curious to see what you have to say. Any particular reason you chose to do it this way? Someone reading this later is going to have a hard time deciphering this, as opposed to what I showed above (which, as I said, *is* a hack, but is at least readable).

Comment: Fair enough. When I saw that there was no internal way to do it, I used the hack that made immediate sense to me (working within the alphabetizing). I agree yours is the less hacky of the hacks, but thought I should write down mine for completeness. Downvote away!