# Reorder columns in pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe created using the pivot_table method. It is structured as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas 

datadict = {
 ('Imps', '10day avg'): {'All': '17,617,872', 'Crossnet': np.nan, 'N/A': '17,617,872'},
 ('Imps', '30day avg'): {'All': '17,302,111', 'Crossnet': '110','N/A': '18,212,742'},
 ('Imps', '3day avg'): {'All': '8,029,438', 'Crossnet': '116', 'N/A': '8,430,904'},
 ('Imps', 'All'): {'All': '14,156,666', 'Crossnet': '113', 'N/A': '14,644,823'},
 ('Spend', '10day avg'): {'All': '$439', 'Crossnet': np.nan, 'N/A': '$439'},
 ('Spend', '30day avg'): {'All': '$468', 'Crossnet': '$0', 'N/A': '$492'},
 ('Spend', '3day avg'): {'All': '$209', 'Crossnet': '$0', 'N/A': '$219'},
 ('Spend', 'All'): {'All': '$368', 'Crossnet': '$0', 'N/A': '$381'}
}
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(datadict)
df.columns = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns)
```

I tried to reorder the nested columns under 'Spend' and 'Imps' in a new order using both of the below methods, however the order remains unchanged despite no errors being thrown:

```
df['Spend']=df['Spend'].reindex_axis(['3day avg','10day avg','30day avg','All'],axis=1)
df['Spend']=df['Spend'][['3day avg','10day avg','30day avg','All']]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to create the MultiIndex and reindex by that:

```
In [11]: mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Imps', 'Spend'], ['3day avg','10day avg','30day avg','All']])

In [12]: df.reindex_axis(mi, 1)
Out[12]: 
               Imps                                        Spend                          
           3day avg   10day avg   30day avg         All 3day avg 10day avg 30day avg   All
All       8,029,438  17,617,872  17,302,111  14,156,666     $209      $439      $468  $368
Crossnet        116         NaN         110         113       $0       NaN        $0    $0
N/A       8,430,904  17,617,872  18,212,742  14,644,823     $219      $439      $492  $381
```

*Note: `MultiIndex.from_product` is new in 0.13, if you're using a pandas older than that use `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(itertools.product(..)))`.*

Comment: I'm on pandas 0.11 so I guess I'm stuck with the 2nd solution. Any reason why there isn't a built-in way to do this even in the new version?

Comment: @ChrisArmstrong It could be there is a neater way, certainly seems like there could be. Could be worth posting enh request on github :

Comment: I tried your solution like this: mi=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(itertools.product([['Imps', 'Spend'], ['3day avg','10day avg','30day avg','All']]))). Is that correct, because I get an error when doing the next step df.reindex_axis(mi, 1)

Comment: @ChrisArmstrong ah, there shouldn't be double brackets :) so ...product(['Imps', 'Spend'], ['3day avg','10day avg','30day avg','All'])